# How does "|" operator evaluate two integers?

Tags: c++

I have something that I haven't yet wrapped my head around yet; how does the `|` operand evaluate numbers?

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int x, y, z;
    x = 2;
    y = 4;

    z = x | y;
}
```

Why does `z` get assigned 6 in this case; how does this work?

Comment: *bitwise*. Concepts required: Bits, binary representation, logical operations. Nice to have: Boolean algebra.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: The one i have dosen't explain in detail

Comment: You should get a better one then.

Answer (score 8):

The operator `|` is called **bitwise OR**. and its truth table is

```
A  B   A|B ( operate on bits)
----------
0  0    0
0  1    1
1  0    1
1  1    1
```

In your case `x=2` and  `y=4`. By assuming both `x` and `y` are 32 bit integer, while doing `x | y` just follow above table. It looks like

```
    MSB                                        LSB <-- little enidian
x = 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0010
                                                |
y = 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0100                                           
-------------------------------------------------
z = 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0110 => 6
--------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

`|` means bitwise OR. The OR is applied to each bit. (4 becomes 100, 2 becomes 10):

```
   4    0100
OR 2    0010
------------
== 6    0110
------------
```

Together the [bitwise OR](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators) produces 110 which is 6.

---

Please note that this is not an addition and there is no carry of the bits like with the `+` operator.

So for example:

```
   6    0110
 + 2    0010
------------
== 8    1000
------------
```

but:

```
   6    0110
OR 2    0010
------------
== 6    0110
------------
```

Comment: Silly me I think i get now  @wally

Comment: So it performing a boolean logic with OR  100V10-->110 cause this makes alot of sense

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. '|' is called bitwise operator. It will return 1 if either of bits are 1. If both bits are 0, this operator will return 0.

x = 2 which is 0000 0010 (in bits representation)
y = 4 which is 0000 0100

now if you apply '|', the result will become 0000 0110 which is 6.